# Flutter problem: Lost connection to device

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, android-studio, dart

This error keeps coming up don't know why or how to solve it. Other times it just says: **Error connecting to service protocol** or **fatal exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getMainExecutor**. I've tried different android emulators, flutter clean, and every other solutions found online, but no results yet. The projects builds with no error but doesn't seem to install or connect on the android emulators.

**flutter run --verbose:**

```
[+7942 ms] √  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
[ +193 ms] executing: C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\32.1.0-rc1\aapt dump xmltree
C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Bureaublad\taxi_app\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[ +240 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\32.1.0-rc1\aapt dump xmltree
C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Bureaublad\taxi_app\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[   +2 ms] N: android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
             E: manifest (line=2)
               A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0x1
               A: android:versionName(0x0101021c)="1.0.0" (Raw: "1.0.0")
               A: android:compileSdkVersion(0x01010572)=(type 0x10)0x1f
               A: android:compileSdkVersionCodename(0x01010573)="12" (Raw: "12")
               A: package="com.praveeshramroop.athena" (Raw: "com.praveeshramroop.athena")
               A: platformBuildVersionCode=(type 0x10)0x1f
               A: platformBuildVersionName=(type 0x10)0xc
               E: uses-sdk (line=7)
                 A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x17
                 A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x1f
               E: uses-permission (line=14)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.INTERNET" (Raw: "android.permission.INTERNET")
               E: uses-permission (line=15)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" (Raw: "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION")
               E: uses-permission (line=16)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" (Raw: "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION")
               E: meta-data (line=18)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="flutterEmbedding" (Raw: "flutterEmbedding")
                 A: android:value(0x01010024)=(type 0x10)0x2
               E: uses-permission (line=22)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" (Raw: "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK")
               E: uses-permission (line=23)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" (Raw: "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE")
               E: uses-permission (line=24)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" (Raw: "android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS")
               E: uses-permission (line=25)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" (Raw: "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE")
               E: uses-permission (line=26)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID")
               E: uses-permission (line=27)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" (Raw:
                 "com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE")
               E: uses-feature (line=29)
                 A: android:glEsVersion(0x01010281)=(type 0x11)0x20000
                 A: android:required(0x0101028e)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
               E: queries (line=33)
                 E: package (line=36)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.apps.maps" (Raw: "com.google.android.apps.maps")
               E: application (line=39)
                 A: android:label(0x01010001)="txapita" (Raw: "txapita")
                 A: android:icon(0x01010002)=@0x7f080000
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.app.Application" (Raw: "android.app.Application")
                 A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                 A: android:extractNativeLibs(0x010104ea)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 A: android:appComponentFactory(0x0101057a)="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" (Raw: "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory")      
                 E: meta-data (line=46)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" (Raw: "com.google.android.geo.API_KEY")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)="AIzaSyC9Csx5p389I16yN3ar0DKLrehQbezEJ0E" (Raw: "AIzaSyC9Csx5p389I16yN3ar0DKLrehQbezEJ0E")
                 E: activity (line=50)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x7f0b0000
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.praveeshramroop.athena.MainActivity" (Raw: "com.praveeshramroop.athena.MainActivity")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x1
                   A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x400037b4
                   A: android:windowSoftInputMode(0x0101022b)=(type 0x11)0x10
                   A: android:hardwareAccelerated(0x010102d3)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: intent-filter (line=66)
                     E: action (line=67)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.MAIN" (Raw: "android.intent.action.MAIN")
                     E: category (line=69)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" (Raw: "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
                   E: intent-filter (line=71)
                     E: action (line=72)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" (Raw: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK")
                     E: category (line=74)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" (Raw: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT")
                 E: service (line=78)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService" (Raw:
                   "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   A: android:directBootAware(0x01010505)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: meta-data (line=82)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore.FlutterFirebaseFirestoreRegistrar" 
                     (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore.FlutterFirebaseFirestoreRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=85)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth.FlutterFirebaseAuthRegistrar" (Raw:     
                     "com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth.FlutterFirebaseAuthRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=88)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseAppRegistrar" (Raw: 
                     "com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseAppRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=91)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCoreRegistrar" (Raw:     
                     "com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCoreRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=94)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=97)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=100)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.storage.StorageRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.storage.StorageRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=103)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.firestore.FirestoreRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.firestore.FirestoreRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=106)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=109)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.datatransport.TransportRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.datatransport.TransportRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=112)
                     A:
                     android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.AnalyticsConnectorRegistrar
                     " (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.AnalyticsConnectorRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=115)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsRegistrar" (Raw:  
                     "com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                 E: service (line=119)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService" (Raw:
                   "io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService")
                   A: android:permission(0x01010006)="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" (Raw: "android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: service (line=123)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService" (Raw:
                   "io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   E: intent-filter (line=126)
                     E: action (line=127)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT")
                 E: receiver (line=131)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingReceiver" (Raw:
                   "io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingReceiver")
                   A: android:permission(0x01010006)="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" (Raw: "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: intent-filter (line=135)
                     E: action (line=136)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" (Raw: "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")
                 E: provider (line=140)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingInitProvider" (Raw:
                   "io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingInitProvider")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   A: android:authorities(0x01010018)="com.praveeshramroop.athena.flutterfirebasemessaginginitprovider" (Raw:
                   "com.praveeshramroop.athena.flutterfirebasemessaginginitprovider")
                   A: android:initOrder(0x0101001a)=(type 0x10)0x63
                 E: activity (line=146)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x01030007
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.WebViewActivity" (Raw: "io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.WebViewActivity")   
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: service (line=151)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.lyokone.location.FlutterLocationService" (Raw: "com.lyokone.location.FlutterLocationService")
                   A: android:enabled(0x0101000e)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   A: android:foregroundServiceType(0x01010599)=(type 0x11)0x8
                 E: activity (line=157)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x01030010
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.auth.internal.GenericIdpActivity" (Raw:
                   "com.google.firebase.auth.internal.GenericIdpActivity")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:excludeFromRecents(0x01010017)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x2
                   E: intent-filter (line=163)
                     E: action (line=164)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.VIEW" (Raw: "android.intent.action.VIEW")
                     E: category (line=166)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" (Raw: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT")
                     E: category (line=167)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" (Raw: "android.intent.category.BROWSABLE")
                     E: data (line=169)
                       A: android:scheme(0x01010027)="genericidp" (Raw: "genericidp")
                       A: android:host(0x01010028)="firebase.auth" (Raw: "firebase.auth")
                       A: android:path(0x0101002a)="/" (Raw: "/")
                 E: activity (line=175)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x01030010
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.auth.internal.RecaptchaActivity" (Raw:
                   "com.google.firebase.auth.internal.RecaptchaActivity")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:excludeFromRecents(0x01010017)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x2
                   E: intent-filter (line=181)
                     E: action (line=182)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.VIEW" (Raw: "android.intent.action.VIEW")
                     E: category (line=184)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" (Raw: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT")
                     E: category (line=185)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" (Raw: "android.intent.category.BROWSABLE")
                     E: data (line=187)
                       A: android:scheme(0x01010027)="recaptcha" (Raw: "recaptcha")
                       A: android:host(0x01010028)="firebase.auth" (Raw: "firebase.auth")
                       A: android:path(0x0101002a)="/" (Raw: "/")
                 E: uses-library (line=194)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="androidx.window.extensions" (Raw: "androidx.window.extensions")
                   A: android:required(0x0101028e)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: uses-library (line=197)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="androidx.window.sidecar" (Raw: "androidx.window.sidecar")
                   A: android:required(0x0101028e)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: receiver (line=201)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" (Raw:
                   "com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver")
                   A: android:permission(0x01010006)="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" (Raw: "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: intent-filter (line=205)
                     E: action (line=206)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" (Raw: "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")
                 E: service (line=213)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService" (Raw:
                   "com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   A: android:directBootAware(0x01010505)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: intent-filter (line=217)
                     A: android:priority(0x0101001c)=(type 0x10)0xfffffe0c
                     E: action (line=218)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT")
                 E: provider (line=222)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" (Raw:
                   "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   A: android:authorities(0x01010018)="com.praveeshramroop.athena.firebaseinitprovider" (Raw:
                   "com.praveeshramroop.athena.firebaseinitprovider")
                   A: android:initOrder(0x0101001a)=(type 0x10)0x64
                   A: android:directBootAware(0x01010505)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                 E: receiver (line=229)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver" (Raw:
                   "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver")
                   A: android:enabled(0x0101000e)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: service (line=235)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService" (Raw:
                   "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService")
                   A: android:enabled(0x0101000e)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: service (line=239)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService" (Raw:
                   "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService")
                   A: android:permission(0x01010006)="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" (Raw: "android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE")
                   A: android:enabled(0x0101000e)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: uses-library (line=244)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="org.apache.http.legacy" (Raw: "org.apache.http.legacy")
                   A: android:required(0x0101028e)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: activity (line=248)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x01030010
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" (Raw:
                   "com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: meta-data (line=253)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.version" (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.version")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)=@0x7f060000
                 E: service (line=257)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.backends.TransportBackendDiscovery" (Raw:
                   "com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.backends.TransportBackendDiscovery")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   E: meta-data (line=260)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="backend:com.google.android.datatransport.cct.CctBackendFactory" (Raw:
[  +48 ms] executing: C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 forward tcp:0 tcp:41253
[ +562 ms] 63706
[   +2 ms] Forwarded host port 63706 to device port 41253 for Observatory
[ +139 ms] Caching compiled dill
[ +413 ms] Connecting to service protocol: http://127.0.0.1:63706/zD4fjyFFW_s=/
[ +961 ms] Launching a Dart Developer Service (DDS) instance at http://127.0.0.1:0, connecting to VM service at http://127.0.0.1:63706/zD4fjyFFW_s=/.     
[+1089 ms] DDS is listening at http://127.0.0.1:63714/hGA51_XOf6Q=/.
[ +649 ms] Successfully connected to service protocol: http://127.0.0.1:63706/zD4fjyFFW_s=/
[+8314 ms] D/FlutterLocationService( 6516): Creating service.
[  +80 ms] D/FlutterLocationService( 6516): Binding to location service.
[+10590 ms] Service protocol connection closed.
[ +391 ms] Lost connection to device.
```

**flutter doctor:**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel unknown, 3.0.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.1335], locale en-US)
Checking Android licenses is taking an unexpectedly long time...[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.2.1)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.73.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

**pubspec.yaml** file:

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"


 
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: 
  cupertino_icons: null
  firebase_auth: 
  firebase_core: 
  firebase_messaging:
  flutter_google_places: null
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
  geocoder: 
  geoflutterfire: 
  geolocator: ^7.7.0
  google_maps_flutter: null
  google_maps_webservice: null
  http: null
  location: ^4.4.0
  modal_bottom_sheet: ^2.0.1
  percent_indicator: ^4.2.1
  provider: null
  rxdart: any
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  uuid: null
  url_launcher: ^6.0.5
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  plugin_platform_interface: 
  geolocator_platform_interface: 
  geocoding: 2.0.5
  google_api_availability:
  google_api_headers: ^1.1.1
  mockito: ^5.2.0
```

**main.dart** page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:athena/providers/app_state.dart';
import 'package:athena/providers/user.dart';
import 'package:athena/screens/login.dart';
import 'package:athena/screens/splash.dart';
import 'locators/service_locator.dart';
import 'screens/home.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  setupLocator();
  return runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider<AppStateProvider>.value(
        value: AppStateProvider(),
      ),
      ChangeNotifierProvider<UserProvider>.value(
        value: UserProvider.initialize(),
      ),
    ],
    child: MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Athena',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    UserProvider auth = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);
    switch (auth.status) {
      case Status.Uninitialized:
        return Splash();
      case Status.Unauthenticated:
      case Status.Authenticating:
        return LoginScreen();
      case Status.Authenticated:
        return MyHomePage();
      default:
        return LoginScreen();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Praveesh Ramroop I have exactly the same problem, did you found any solution? Can you help me, please?

Comment: Dear @Isabel, I have just posted my solution below. Hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the **android/build.gradle** file, specifically the code block below:

```
subprojects {
        project.configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                    details.useVersion "27.1.1"
                }
                if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('androidx') ) {
                    details.useVersion "1.0.1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By removing the block I was able to run the app on my phone just fine.